# Excel - get the highest number in a certain column, that contains text

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have these two sheets, that I'm using to keep track of my work. In one of the sheets, I have my overview, where I can see all of my tasks at hand. In other sheets, I have the different jobs I'm currently doing.

Now... I'm looking for at formula for Microsoft Excel, where I can do the following:

="GET THE HIGHEST ROW-NUMBER, IN A CERTAIN COLUMN, THAT ISN'T EMPTY, AND PUT THE TEXT FROM THAT COLUMN INTO ANOTHER CELL" (see examples of it further down)

Examples:
Let's say, that I insert this formula into D10, and to check the entire A-column, then this would be the result

Ex.1

```
      A      B      C      D    
1    Foo
2    Bar
3    Is
4    An
5    Apple
6    From
7    Chile
8
9
10                       Chile
```

Ex.2

```
      A      B      C      D    
1    Foo
2    Bar
3    Is
4    An
5    Apple
6    
7    
8
9
10                       Apple
```

Ex.3

```
      A      B      C      D    
1    Foo
2    Bar
3    Is
4    
5    
6    
7    
8
9
10                         Is
```

Ex.4

```
          A          B          C          D    
1    Foo bar is
2    Also an
3    Egyptian God
4    Of pie
5    
6    
7    
8
9
10                                       Of pie
```

On a last remark... Then I'm using this stupid danish version of Excel, so if you're a dane trying to solve this, then a danish formula would be 'B-E-A-UTIFUL'.

And remember, that it has to work across different sheets.

MY ATTEMPTS:

I Google around for about an hour... I found this, which I tried to understand:

=INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("R",MATCH(MAX(S4:S5),S4:S5,0)+3))

But I couldn't get it to work, because of this stupid danish Excel. I tried to understand it, then - and figured out, that it parsed and concatenated area as text and inserted that into the field - so I guess that wouldn't do the trick anyways.

Then my idea was to try to loop through all the cells in a column and check each of the cells, if they weren't empty, and if their row-number where higher than then previous. I quickly gave up on that one, because I couldn't find a way to make a for loop in Excel.

Then I've tried all other sorts of things (mainly experimenting with the MAX()-function).

Comment: `And remember, that is has to work across different sheets.` That's pretty demanding :D Please show us what have you tried? Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved.Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: Ok... Adding my feeble attempts, then. Hang on. I'm not proud of them, though.

Comment: You might want to see my reply [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20149349/countif-using-last-row-with-data-in-excel) It covers both Data and Numbers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your data is in a sheet called **data** then try this formula to get the last text value in column A of that sheet

`=LOOKUP(REPT("z";255);Data!A:A)`

In Danish that should be

`=SLÅ.OP(GENTAG("z";255);Data!A:A)`